# How to run a command in a container from another container

Tags: docker, security, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Python script that runs PHPStan using their docker image (https://phpstan.org/user-guide/docker) like this:

```python
command = f"docker run --rm -v $PWD:/app ghcr.io/phpstan/phpstan --error-format=json analyse /app"
subprocess.Popen(f"{command}", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Now I'd like to dockerize everything.
I tried to create a docker-compose file to create two containers, one to execute my Python script and the other to execute Phpstan.

But I do not find a way to call PHPStan from my Python container. What's the proper way to do it?

For now, the only solution I found is to create this Dockerfile to copy all the content of Psalm's container to my Python's container :

```
FROM ghcr.io/phpstan/phpstan:latest AS phpstan

FROM python:alpine AS python

COPY --from=phpstan / /
```

I intend to have multiple tools in different containers because the images already exist and then call them from a script in my Python's container. Do you have an idea how to do it securely?